# Error with IV-regression, no endogenous/instrument variables

Tags: r

Hey guys I would like to run the following IV-Regression but the error

```
Error in ivdiag(object, vcov. = vcov.) : 
  no endogenous/instrument variables
```

appears. Does anyone know how to handle this or if there is any variable/library missing?

```
install.packages("psych")
library(MASS)
library(psych)

set.seed(1234)

n <- 2000
pi1 <- -0.1
b0 <- 0
b1 <- 0
b2 <- -1/1000
b3 <- 1/5

z <- runif(n,0,25)
ov <- rnorm(n,0,1)

d <- -1/2 + pi1 * z + 1/2 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1) > 0
y <- b0 + b1 * d + b2 * z + b3 * ov + rnorm(n,0,1/10)



model11 = ivreg(y ~ d | z)
summary(model11)
```

Best regards,
Freddy

Comment: Are you using the `ivreg` function from `ivpack`? You should add to the code `library(...)` of wherever the `ivreg` function is from.

Comment: yes I already incorporated the libray(ivreg). It still displays the same error

Comment: I meant in this posted question to help us

Comment: It looks like we don't need `MASS` and `psych` packages for this code, right? Please edit the code in the post to only include the packages that we will be needing to reproduce your error. Thanks.